# ORA-01722- Invalid Number

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01722

I have a query in the package throwing error

> **ORA-01722** : invalid number.

I tried many ways but no luck.

```
select h.column  
  from table1 h,table2 c 
 where c.created_date='17-MAY-17' 
   and nvl(c.acct_nmbr,0)=nvl(to_number(h.v_acct_num),0)
```

- `c.acct_nmbr` is of `NUMBER(19,0)`
- `h.v_acct_num` is of `varchar2(4000 byte)`

Please suggest me the solution

Comment: Does h.v_acct_num hold any alphanumeric data?

Comment: The best solution is to no store numbers in `varchar` columns and re-define `v_acct_num` to `number`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously `v_acct_num` column contains non-numeric values. `to_number()` function has restriction that the value in the argument shouldn't contain any non-numeric character, otherwise the system hurls with `ORA-01722 : invalid number`. If you're sure about the data matches when non-numeric characters are extracted then use `regexp_replace(t2.v_acct_num,'[^[:digit:]]')` within the collation of the `join`'s `on` clause :

```
select t2.column  
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on nvl(t1.acct_nmbr,0) = nvl(regexp_replace(t2.v_acct_num,'[^[:digit:]]'),0)
 where t2.created_date = date'2017-05-17'
```

*Use `ANSI-92` standard for `Join`, and `ISO-8601` standard for `date` syntaxes.*

Answer (score 7):

If you are using **Oracle 12.2 or higher** then you can use the `TO_NUMBER` with `ON CONVERSION ERROR` clause as follows:

```
SELECT
    H.COLUMN
FROM
    TABLE1 H
    JOIN TABLE2 C 
    ON NVL(C.ACCT_NMBR, 0) = NVL(TO_NUMBER(H.V_ACCT_NUM DEFAULT -999 ON CONVERSION ERROR), 0)
    -- use any number which is impossible in your column 
    -- so that it do not match any random records.
WHERE
    C.CREATED_DATE = DATE '2017-05-17';
```

Note:

- Use standard **ANSI** joins
- Use `DATE` literal wherever you want to convert string to date or `TO_DATE` function

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

#### Identify what data is non-numeric:

```
select * from table1 h
where regexp_like(h.v_acct_num, '[^0-9]')
```

#### and delete them

.

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this looks like a good idea on first glance, it doesn't work (or you would be just lucky if it did). The reason is that there is nothing that would force Oracle to evaluate `and NOT regexp_like(h.v_acct_num, '[^0-9]')` (and dismiss the non-numeric rows) before trying to convert the column in `and nvl(c.acct_nmbr,0)=nvl(to_number(h.v_acct_num),0)`.