# Getting "ORA-01722: invalid number" Error while in outer query tried to find number is null or less than some number

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find values where "id_case"(here id_case is number ) is null or less than 1 but getting "ORA-01722: invalid number
", query is like follwing:

```
SELECT v.id, v.id_case_p, v.id_case FROM (
SELECT p.id, to_number(replace(p.description,'xyy_','')) as id_case_p, c.id as id_case 
FROM t_processes p left join t_cases c on to_number(replace(p.description,'xyz_','')) = c.id 
where p.active ='Y' and p.id_process_step < 10 
)v 
WHERE v.id_case < 1
;
```

I have also tried like below, but getting same error.

```
SELECT v.id, v.id_case_p, v.id_case FROM (
    SELECT p.id, to_number(replace(p.description,'xyy_','')) as id_case_p, c.id as id_case 
    FROM t_processes p left join t_cases c on to_number(replace(p.description,'xyz_','')) = c.id 
    where p.active ='Y' and p.id_process_step < 10 
    )v 
    WHERE v.id_case is null
    ;
```

any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that `p.description` have values containing strings other than `xyy_`, https://dbfiddle.uk/y8dK_hrK

Comment: I'd rather use to_number(replace(p.description,'xyy_','') default null on conversion error). One can't be sure whether that value in the description column may always be converted to number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-01722- Invalid Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871685/ora-01722-invalid-number)

Comment: This is a weird data model where an ID is hidden in a description text. If processes refer to cases, then add a case_id to the process table.

Answer (score 2):

Please run:

```
  SELECT p.id, to_number(replace(p.description,'xyy_','') default null on 
    conversion error) as id_case_p, c.id as id_case 
  FROM t_processes p 
  left join MD2.t_cases c on to_number(replace(p.description,'xyz_','') default null on conversion error) = c.id 
  where p.active ='Y' and p.id_process_step < 10 ;
```

And see what you get.

Also run:

```
SELECT p.* 
 FROM t_processes p
 where  to_number(replace(p.description,'xyy_','') default null on 
    conversion error) is null
```

And see what this returns.